# Running Gazebo under Docker with VirtualGL

Tags: docker

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to run the [LRAUV Simulator](https://github.com/osrf/lrauv) on a headless system with an NVIDIA GPU, which I access over VNC.

The simulator is published as a [Docker container](https://github.com/osrf/lrauv/wiki/Installation). I modified this container to add [VirtualGL](https://virtualgl.org) as well as the `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `libegl1-mesa` packages. Then, following [these examples](https://github.com/dcommander/virtualgl_docker_examples) of running a hardware accelerated program inside a container with VirtualGL, I invoke Gazebo like this:

```
xauth merge /etc/opt/VirtualGL/vgl_xauth_key
rm -f ~/.Xauthority.docker
xauth nlist $DISPLAY :0.0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f ~/.Xauthority.docker nmerge -

docker run --rm -it \
    --user $(id -u):$(getent group vglusers | cut -d : -f 3) \
    --gpus all \
    --device=/dev/dri \
    --ipc host \
    -e DISPLAY \
    -e MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 \
    --mount=type=bind,src=$HOME/.Xauthority.docker,dst=/home/developer/.Xauthority,ro \
    --mount=type=bind,src=/tmp/.X11-unix,dst=/tmp/.X11-unix,ro \
    osrf/lrauv:latest \
    vglrun gz sim -v4
```

This appears to work and I can see the simulated environment if I load some of the examples like `multi_lrauv_race.sdf`.

However, if I try to run the  `tethys_at_portuguese_ledge.sdf` or `tethys_at_empty_environment.sdf` files, Gazebo starts and then terminates. [Here is the complete log](https://gist.github.com/rgov/b44c9b89d06ad57d012ba018e3683c1f), with the part that looks to be the error below.

I am unsure where to go from here due to the fact that other SDFs work OK... Is this some unexpected weirdness from the way I'm running it with VirtualGL? Is this a bug in Gazebo? Is it an issue with the SDF I'm trying to load?

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create dri screen
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create dri screen
[Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1098]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /home/jenkins/workspace/ogre-2.3-debbuilder/repo/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
(... above repeated a few times ...)
[Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1106] Unable to create the rendering window after [11] attempts.
[Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1017] Failed to create dummy render window.

Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 125:
#24   Object "[0xffffffffffffffff]", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
#23   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7fa89a64f132, in clone
#22   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", at 0x7fa89a119608, in 
#21   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", at 0x7fa896708de3, in 
#20   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/gz-sim-7/plugins/libgz-sim-sensors-system.so", at 0x7fa85c1a85b7, in gz::sim::v7::systems::SensorsPrivate::RenderThread()
#19   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/gz-sim-7/plugins/libgz-sim-sensors-system.so", at 0x7fa85c1a6f08, in gz::sim::v7::systems::SensorsPrivate::WaitForInit()
#18   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/libgz-sim7-rendering.so.7", at 0x7fa85c0c4c23, in gz::sim::v7::RenderUtil::Init()
#17   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0x7fa85bec9b57, in gz::rendering::v7::RenderEngineManager::Engine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#16   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0x7fa85bec994e, in gz::rendering::v7::RenderEngineManagerPrivate::Engine(EngineInfo, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#15   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0x7fa85bed7b61, in gz::rendering::v7::BaseRenderEngine::Init()
#14   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/gz-rendering-7/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0x7fa8586061ee, in gz::rendering::v7::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitImpl()
#13   Object "/home/developer/gz_ws/install/lib/gz-rendering-7/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0x7fa858603c47, in gz::rendering::v7::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitAttempt()
#12   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa84853fc88, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::initialiseAllResourceGroups(bool)
#11   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa84853f6f6, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::parseResourceGroupScripts(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::ResourceGroup*)
#10   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa848588c51, in Ogre::ScriptCompilerManager::parseScript(Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::DataStream>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#9    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa848588ade, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#8    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa8485887f2, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(Ogre::SharedPtr<std::__cxx11::list<Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::ConcreteNode>, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::ConcreteNode>, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#7    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa8485983f5, in Ogre::MaterialTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa848593391, in Ogre::ScriptTranslator::processNode(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa84859e6c8, in Ogre::TechniqueTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa848593391, in Ogre::ScriptTranslator::processNode(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa8485b36cc, in Ogre::PassTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#2    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa84861e269, in Ogre::Technique::createPass()
#1    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa8484e8cd4, in Ogre::Pass::Pass(Ogre::Technique*, unsigned short)
#0    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0x7fa8483e9c1a, in Ogre::Hlms::createDatablock(Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Ogre::HlmsMacroblock const&, Ogre::HlmsBlendblock const&, std::vector<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x220])
[GUI] [Dbg] [SignalHandler.cc:141] Received signal[2].
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28660/running-gazebo-under-docker-with-virtualgl/) by [rgov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65822/rgov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like [this bug](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1746) is tracking the issue. A workaround is provided: Pass `--headless-rendering`.

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65822/rgov/) with karma: 11 on 2022-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0